# Certificate match to private key

Tags: java, cryptography, public-key

We are currently implementing a digital signature applet in java. Users will have tokens containing keystores of private keys and their respective certificates. The certificates and private keys will have different aliases.

What I need to do is call/match the private key in the store to the certificate selected by the user at the time of signing. How can I match a private key to its respective certificate in java? I need something like getkey(alias, password) where alias is derived from a match between the certificate selected and the key.

Comment: A private is just what it is - a key... There is no way to match it against a certificate (public key). Of couse, you know the private key for a given certificate at time of selection as they are stored togather in your keystore. Just keep both of them togather (tuple).

Comment: Theolodis, currently trying hash matching via the mod of both (after getting the public key from the ceet)

Comment: Home, thats not entirely accurate. Public and private keys can be matched, thats the whole point

Comment: I'm not sure your implementation is a good way to go with - see the javadoc: 
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry
This type of entry holds a cryptographic PrivateKey, which is optionally stored in a protected format to prevent unauthorized access. It is also accompanied by a certificate chain for the corresponding public key.

Private keys and certificate chains are used by a given entity for self-authentication. Applications for this authentication include software distribution organizations which sign JAR files as part of releasing and/or licensing software.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ECC then

```
Q = k * P
```

Where **Q** is your public key, so when you know the private key **k** you also know the base point **P** and the curve so you can "easily" compute the public key.

The issue with RSA is also simple, when using well known implementations, where exponent e is fixed. If it's not fixed it can be tricky, but also not that hard.

The completly other issue is... how would you match given pubkey with stored certificate? And the other question is why do something like this ? You should hold cert info after sign and access coresponding cert in java key store. Ambiguity is always a problem, specially in crypto you should be as explicit as you can be.

Comment: So,  a little more clarity. We are using pkcs#11. Certificate requests are generated automatically, and private keys are stored on tokens with aliases being 00000001.key etc. depending on the request number. Certificates are then sent back by a CA and also stored on the token. This certificates are aliased for ease of a clients use. When signing, the client selects the relevent certificate. However the signing operation requires both the certificate and its relavent private key. Thus the need to find it.

Comment: And you cannot change private key alias (to maybe <public_key_alias>_priv) after CSR is back from your CA ? Or store private key with cert after getting the response with proper aliases? Otherwise this will be problematic... Because iterating over private keys is BAD idea. You must have some explicit connection, maybe you can add some attr to your certificate that will point to private key alias but someone may consider it a information disclosure ;)

Comment: @BorisOstrovsky normally the certificate and private key get assigned the same ID in PKCS#11. You should generate the key pair and the certificate in the same PKCS#11 token, so when you get send the certificate from somewhere, look it up in your token, then look up the corresponding private key.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your design - your idea is not something that you should proceed with, however java should support what you need:

Use this code:

```
 KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)
 ks.getEntry("privateKeyAlias", password);
 Certificate certificateFromPrivateKey = pkEntry.getCertificate();
 KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry certEntry = (KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry)ks.getEntry("certificateAlias, password);
 Certificate certificateFromPublicKey = certEntry.getCertificate();

 if (certificateFromPrivateKey.equals(certificateFromPublicKey)) ...
```

Read more about it in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) - but I really think you are going about this the wrong way.

Also - a relevant API (I assume you are using it) - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html

Comment: A little bit backwards I think. We need to find the private key (could br many in the store) based on the certificate selected by the user